# Fill middle indexes of array with empty string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading from an excel sheet through php code. There some fields are optional. when i use the library i get the result like this

```
Array
    (
    [1] => Test123
    [2] => None
    [3] => Booster
    [6] => Yes
    [7] => Yes
    [8] => 1
    [9] => Unknown
    [10] => 21
    [11] => http://unknowm.com
    )
```

There you can see index 4 and 5 are missing because the values were not present in the excel file columns. Now i have to merge this array with another array which has named indexes. the length of the second array is 11. But when i merge both a php error is produced saying undefined index 4 and 5. i am doing the work dynamically and i am compelled to use all the indexes of second array. i wnt the first(coming from excel) array indexes which are missing to be filled with empty string before mergin it to the second one. How can i do this? i hope i have provided much information.

Comment: What is your end-goal ? Why do you want to merge these both arrays ?
And can you get an assoc array from the excel, rather than normal array with gaps ?

Comment: well i have to insert it into db and i dont want to use isset on each array index

Comment: which library are you using to read excel ? how you are reading excel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to create an array with all the keys you want the result to have and use the array addition operator to add those that are missing from the original array:

```
$firstIndexToEnsure = 1;
$lastIndexToEnsure = 11;
$defaults = array_fill($firstIndexToEnsure,
                       $lastIndexToEnsure - $firstIndexToEnsure + 1,
                       '');
$array += $defaults;
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/1Xy41).

If you need the result to be additionally ordered by key then also use `ksort` on it.

It's worthwhile to mention that this technique works very well for non-integer keys too wherever you accept user input that may only partially override some defaults:

```
$params = array('color' => 'blue', 'size' => 'large');
$defaults = array(
    'color' => 'red',
    'size'  => 'large',
    'shape' => 'square',
    'age'   => 'old',
);

$params += $defaults;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
$array = array(
    0 => "a",
    2 => "b",
    4 => "b",
    5 => "b",
    6 => "b",
);

// If min and max are static, use numbers instead of getting them from the array
$keys = array_keys($array);
$all = array_fill(min($keys), max($keys) - min($keys) + 1, "");
$filled = $array + $all;

var_dump($filled);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the first array complete:

```
$lastindex = 11;
for($i=1; $i<=$lastindex; $i++)
  if( !isset($array[$i] ))
    $array[$i] = '';
```

Now you can easy merge with the second array.